# Creating new columns in pandas with shift and assign

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make many new columns only by shifting the `'amount_in_group_currency'` column, here is my approach:

```
pay_history_by_interv = (temp.assign(due_amount= temp['amount_in_group_currency'])
                    .assign(period_1= temp['amount_in_group_currency'].shift(1))
                    .assign(period_2= temp['amount_in_group_currency'].shift(2))
                    .assign(period_3= temp['amount_in_group_currency'].shift(3))
                    .assign(period_4= temp['amount_in_group_currency'].shift(4))
                    .assign(period_5= temp['amount_in_group_currency'].shift(5))
                    .assign(period_6= temp['amount_in_group_currency'].shift(6))
                    .drop('amount_in_group_currency', axis=1).fillna(0).reset_index()
                    )
```

This works for a small number of shifts (e.g 6 in my case) but not for much more, is there a "pandas way" to automate this column making shifts with any desired number?

Thank you

Comment: What kind of problems are you experiencing exactly when you do it for more shifts? It is not clear from your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is how to automate creation of columns so you do not have to type them by hand for each one, you can use a loop

```
n_shifts = 10 # specify how many shifts you want
for n in range(n_shifts):
    temp[f'period_{n+1}'] = temp['amount_in_group_currency'].shift(n+1)

pay_history_by_interv = temp.drop('amount_in_group_currency', axis=1).fillna(0).reset_index()
```